# is there a way to keep the time in updateview same as the time in createview in django

Tags: python, django

i have realised  that when i run the updateview the listdate changes to the time I updated the listing.Here is my models.py

class Listing(models.Model):

```
list_date = models.DateTimeField('date created', blank=True, auto_now=True)
favourite = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="favourite", blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self): 
   return reverse("user-dashboard") 


def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    if self.is_published and self.list_date is None:
        self.list_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    elif not self.is_published and self.list_date is not None:
        self.list_date = None
    super(Listing, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `auto_now` to `auto_now_add`.

```
list_date = models.DateTimeField('date created', blank=True, auto_now_add=True)
```